# Does not preserve excel connection setting in excel manager in SSIS

Tags: sql, ssis

I have created `SSIS package` which will `generate excel file` from sql table.

But when I try to execute 2nd time that same package after deleting that file (try to generate new file again) i'm getting following error

```
Error at Data Flow Task [Excel Destination [329]]: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80040E37.

Error at Data Flow Task [Excel Destination [329]]: Opening a rowset for "Excel_Destination" failed. Check that the object exists in the database.

Error at Data Flow Task [SSIS.Pipeline]: "component "Excel Destination" (329)" failed validation and returned validation status "VS_ISBROKEN".

Error at Data Flow Task [SSIS.Pipeline]: One or more component failed validation.

Error at Data Flow Task: There were errors during task validation.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix this issue.
In the Excel connection manager properties you have to set the "**DelayValidation**" property to **TRUE**.

Answer (score 0):

To fix this issue. In the Excel connection manager properties you have to set the "DelayValidation" property to TRUE.

> > i think change  "DelayValidation" on Dataflow Properties.

Comment: You should be confident in the answers that you post here, the phrase *i think* seems you are not sure about it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).